# How to limit the number of button clicks in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make the button non-functional after the number of clicks are equal to the value entered in the text boy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Student <input type="input" ng-model="number"> <br> 
<p> {{number}} </p>
<button ng-click= "myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count=0;
$scope.number;
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.count++;
    $scope.count <= $scope.number;
  }
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a Angular 2+ implementation, you could use two-way binding to `ngModel` directive. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  buttonCount = 0;
  studentCount = 0;

  onClick() {
    this.buttonCount++;
  }
}
```

Controller

```html
Student <input [(ngModel)]="studentCount" (keyup)="buttonCount = 0" type="input"> <br> 
Number input: {{ studentCount }}
<br><br>
<button [disabled]="buttonCount >= studentCount" (mouseup)="onClick()">Click me</button>
<br>
Button clicks: {{ buttonCount }}
```

The `(keyup)="buttonCount = 0"` event in the `input` tag resets the button click count everytime a value is entered in the input.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-35vrsf)

If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through [this](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial. It introduces some of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Add a [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) attribute to the button, this will disable the button when the expression is truthy.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Student <input type="input" ng-model="number"> <br> 
<p> {{number}} </p>
<button ng-disabled="count >= number" ng-click= "myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.count=0;
$scope.number;
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.count++;
    $scope.count <= $scope.number;
  }
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

> If you are starting out and can switch, I would recommend trying Angular 2+ instead of AngularJS. It's much more intuitive IMO.

Comment: It would be pretty similar, but with the new syntax and structure, It also uses Typescript BTW so some things are done in different ways, at first it might seem a bit overwhelming but will become easier as you go. if you are learning JS at the moment maybe it's better to stay with AngularJS, or with vanilla js, as these frameworks can abstract things way too much for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-disabled** directive. You can disable the button after the number of clicks.